# Iterating through json values

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Here's is the JSON I am talking about,

```
{
    "0": {
        "entry_id": "4",
        "category_id": "3",
        "title": "lorem ipusm"
    },
    "1": {
        "entry_id": "5",
        "category_id": "3",
        "title": "lorem ipusm dolor"
    },

    ......
    ......

    "total_entry": 270,
    "pending": 7,
    "url": "http://domainhere.tld/url"
}
```

I need to read the values of fields like total_entry, pending etc..and then also need to iterate through all the objects with keys like 0,1 (can go on, only two are shown in this example. This is what I am trying

```
var makelist;
for (var i = 0; i < objData.length; i++) {
    makelist='<li>'+ objData[i].title + '</li>';
}
$('#conatiner').append(makelist);
```

It works for getting the objects with keys like 0,1 but only when the json doesn't contain the other fields (total_entry etc..). How do I read both fields?

Comment: make a fiddle for this?

Comment: Can you amend your JSON format at all? The logic for this would be much simpler if you can keep the `0`, `1` etc objects within an array, and separate from `total_entry`, `pending` etc

Comment: Do you know how many entries are in the JSON? You can still iterate through it the same, but insetad of objData.length you use objData.number_of_entries or similar

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, you mean to say like some `data` property would have collection of all that records later on OP should loop through `jsonObject.Data` property, is it?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, Unfortunately I don't have access to it (provided by third party). So, I am stuck with this format.

Comment: @Lex R. Not known beforehand, it varies.

Comment: Is the number of non-numerical arguments (total_entry, pending etc) the same every time? If so you can use something like [lodash's _.size](https://lodash.com/docs#size) method to find out how many are actually there and remove that number

Comment: @LexR  Yes, those fields are same every time with only values changing.I will look into your suggestion. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [jQuery each iterate function](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) to iterate the object.

> Description: A generic iterator function, which can be used to
>   seamlessly iterate over both objects and arrays. Arrays and array-like
>   objects with a length property (such as a function's arguments object)
>   are iterated by numeric index, from 0 to length-1. **Other objects are
>   iterated via their named properties**.

Than for each property/key that is **not** [Not-a-Number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) add new list item:

```js
var obj = {
    "0": {
        "entry_id": "4",
        "category_id": "3",
        "title": "Title for item 0"
    },
    "1": {
        "entry_id": "5",
        "category_id": "3",
        "title": "Title for item 1"
    },
    "total_entry": 270,
    "pending": 7,
    "url": "http://domainhere.tld/url"
};
var makelist = '';
$.each(obj, function( i, n ) {
    if ( !isNaN(parseInt(i)) ) makelist+='<li>'+ n.title + '</li>';
});
$('#container').append(makelist);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="container"></ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var myJson = {
    "0": {
        "entry_id": "4",
        "category_id": "3",
        "title": "lorem ipusm"
    },
    "1": {
        "entry_id": "5",
        "category_id": "3",
        "title": "lorem ipusm dolor"
    },
    "50": {
        "entry_id": "50",
        "category_id": "30",
        "title": "lorem ipusm dolor number 50"
    },
    "total_entry": 270,
    "pending": 7,
    "url": "http://domainhere.tld/url"
}

//for all the keys in myJson
for (var k in myJson){

    //get 'title' if key is a number more than -1
    if (k > -1){
        console.log(myJson[k].title)
    }
    else{
        //get value of the key
        console.log(myJson[k])
    }
}
```

Comment: Problem is k can be anything from 0 to 100 + and I don't know the length beforehand.

Comment: you can use another test instead like k > -1. if k is a number more than -1 it will give you the title field, else(if its a string) just give you the value.

Comment: or use isNaN() as a test

Comment: It works. But I decided to go with @skobaljic's solution which is similar but looks neater. Upvoted yours. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use your loop to iterate thru the indexed items in the object and iterate thru the other properties of your object using this syntax:

```
for (var prop in objData) {
  if (objData.hasOwnProperty(prop) && isNaN(prop)) {
    // use objData[prop]
  }
}
```

The hasOwnProperty check will filter out any properties not directly contained in the object (inherited from a base class).

Answer (score 0):

This is how you get the values of all object's keys that are integers:

```
var obj = { '0': 'Zero', 1: 'One', '2': 'Two', somekey: 'somevalue', someotherkey: 'someothervalue' }, propName, arr = [];

for(propName in obj)
{
    if(obj.hasOwnProperty(propName)) // Avoids using keys/values from possibly existing prototype chain.
    {
        if(!isNaN(parseInt(propName, 10))) // Checks, if key name is a number by trying to parse and validating it.
        {
            arr.push(obj[propName]); // Adds key's value to array (as example).
        }
    } 
}

console.log(arr);
```

Just replace sample object with yours and replace the content of the inner if clause with your (makelist) code.

Comment: Working for the objects with 0,1 etc. How do I get the values for 'total_entry' etc?

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through jquery's each function as:

```
var makelist;

$.each(objData, function(i, data){
     makelist = '<li>'+data.title+'</li>';
     $("#conatiner").append(makelist);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use for (.. in ..), then you get all keys and not only the numerical. To check if the value is an object you can use typeof.

```
var makelist = '';
for (var i in obj) {
    if (typeof obj[i] == 'object')
        makelist='<li>'+ obj[i].title + '</li>';
    else 
        makelist += '<li>' + obj[i] + '</li>';
}   

$('#conatiner').append(makelist);
```